# Find the commutator $[I+aE_{i,j},I+bE_{j,r}]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $G=GL_n(K)$ where $K$ is a field, $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix with "1" in the $i,j$ spot and zeros in any other spot. What is the commutator $[I+aE_{i,j},I+bE_{j,r}]$?
For those of you who don't know group theory: what is: $(I+aE_i)(I+bE_i)(I+aE_i)^{-1}(I+bE_i)^{-1}$?
Here's what I tried but I am completely confused. a,b are bigger or equal to 1, which I am not sure how it helps.

[image]

Comment: are you assuming $a \neq -1, b \neq -1?$

Comment: So you don't mean the matrix commutator $[A, B] = AB - BA$? You want the group commutator?

Comment: I want the commutator as it is defined..ghg^-1h^-1

Comment: Abel, yes... Check my edit
How does it contribute?

Comment: You probably want to assume $i \ne j$ rather than $a,b \ne -1$.

Comment: if $a = -1$ and $i = j,$ then $I + aE_{ii}$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1) Prove that $E_{i,j}E_{k,l}=\delta_{j,k}E_{i,l}$.

2) Prove that for $i\neq j$, $(I+aE_{i,j})(I-aE_{i,j})=I$ hence $(I+aE_{i,j})^{-1}=I-aE_{i,j}$.

3) Now, for $i\neq j\neq k$, $[I+aE_{i,j}, I+bE_{j,k}]$ can be computed by expansion into product of four terms, and use (1) and (2) in its simplification.

Comment: The above arguments, with $i\neq j$ (or similar conditions) work in $GL(n,F)$ for any field $F$. The computations (1) and (2) are useful since we do not need to write down the whole matrix, once we prove them.